# I need direction with part names and/or a diagram

Tags: relay

Im suck!!! I have a project with two separate 12v dc connections. I need one to be always on until the second one is activated. When power is there for second 12dc output I need he first one to shut off until there is no longer power for the second connection. I have figured this out by using a relay but I really need this to be as small as possible. Im sure there is something available for this exact application but I have no clue what to search for. Again he smaller the better!!! Any help would be greatly appreciate it!!!! even if its the proper item to search for... TIA

Comment: Make a simple truth table and use high side power switches with logic level tolerances. Got it?

Comment: You're suck?  Don't be so down on yourself!  The only tihng sucky is you forgot to spell check.  The magic words you're looking for are "automatic power transfer switch" although for a small 12V version you might have to build your own.  You need to add more information about your two power sources (what they are, output voltage range, any converters present), your load (same information plus power consumption).  We also need to know how much of a "blip" (voltage change or dropout) is acceptable.  If you can have power drop out for some number of mS, the solution is simpler.

Comment: Its for lighted tail whips for atv/side by side . Using ws2811 for the main lights I want to add a second wrap of solid red lights. What I want to achieve is when the operator uses their brakes I want the reds to turn on like brake lights do while killing power to the ws2811 strip. Then when brakes are released red go off, ws2811 back on for. I can achieve this  by using a normally closed relay but I really don't want to have to use a relay. I want it small enough to be a part of the whip base just like I have the ws2811 controller. Just need the correct keywords to search for.

Comment: This information belgongs into the question.

Comment: If it needs to be as small as possible, you need a power mux like the TPS212x. But searching for specific products is off topic on this site.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what the power output requirements are. As suggested in comments there are dedicates ICs that are power multiplexers (switching between two are more power sources)

This is example schematic that may work, but you would need to verify power load requirements against component specs and verify if there are any transient voltages that exceed component specs.

[image: Schematic example]